# How to use a public bool from one class in another class? c#

Tags: c#, class, xna, boolean

I'm trying to use a bool from class Level in class Health but I can't get it to work. I know it's probably really trivial but right now I'm stuck..

Here's the method Uphealth from class Level:

```
public bool UpHealth()
{
    SpriteGameObject healthpack = this.Find("uphealth") as SpriteGameObject;
    Player player = this.Find("player") as Player;
    if (healthpack.CollidesWith(player))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Here's the method in class Health where I want to use the bool Uphealth:

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    base.Update(gameTime);
    Player player = GameWorld.Find("player") as Player;
    AnimatedGameObject rocket = GameWorld.Find("rocket") as AnimatedGameObject;

    foreach (GameObject obj in gameObjects)
    {
        SpriteGameObject h = obj as SpriteGameObject;
        if ( <---I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO TYPE HERE---> )
        {
            this.Add(h);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to be when Uphealth is true it performs the this.Add(h);

What do I need to do to be able to use Uphealth in the class Health?

Comment: You need an instance of class Level

Answer (score 1):

First, create an instance of the class "Level". The best way to do it is probably in the class declaration (make it a member).

```
Level level;
```

After that, just make sure that it exist.

```
level = new Level(); // <------ I would probably put this in "LoadContent()"
```

And finally, you can use it as such

```
if (level.UpHealth())
{
    // Do really cool stuff here
}
```

I hope that I was of assistance.

Comment: thank you! but I have one problem left: in the construcet of the level class I give a levelindex paramater with it so now I have to figure that out

Comment: if you post the corresponding code for it I could help you out with that aswell! :)

Comment: That would be great! Should I just add a new question? because if put a lot of code in a comment it would be hard to read

Comment: I've posted the question :)